# Where is the middleware key for Laravel Sanctum defined?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

To protect and authenticate all incoming routes in Laravel using Sanctum, we have to attache the `sanctum` authentication guard to our routes within `routes/api.php` route files:

```php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

My question is about the middleware key `auth:sanctum`. Where is it defined/registered?

Comment: There's no specific middleware for sanctum, the `auth` middleware ([here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Http/Kernel.php#L56)) can take parameters and the parameter is the guard name which is typically defined in `config/auth.php` but Sanctum may extend that configuration via its own service provider

Comment: @apokryfos You mean we are using the auth middleware here? `Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')`. Then what does the `auth:sanctum` syntax mean?

Comment: @BFaley.if i understood correctly guard then auth is middleware and sanctum is guard .its like sanctum is  passing extra param to middleware

Answer (score 0):

As document says

> To protect routes so that all incoming requests must be authenticated,
> you should attach the sanctum authentication guard to your protected
> routes within your routes/web.php and routes/api.php route files.

if you see `Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider` in `register method`

```
    public function register()
    {
        config([
                 'auth.guards.sanctum' => array_merge([
                        'driver' => 'sanctum',
                        'provider' => null,
                 ], config('auth.guards.sanctum', [])),
              ]);
        
         if (! app()->configurationIsCached()) {
                    $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/../config/sanctum.php', 'sanctum');
         }
     }
```

While registering they are setting sanctum guard.So sanctum is not middleware its guard

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#protecting-routes

Ref:https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/2.x/src/SanctumServiceProvider.php

Comment: What does this format mean then:  Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified']) ?  Does a logged in user with a "verified" account have that trait or something ?

Comment: I guess you can check:  dd(Auth::user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) . . . . class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail